# Getting "No provider for NgControl" error in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngx-quill

I have added Quilljs editor on my page. I am trying to fetch the valve of the content.

I am following a video on YouTube called "Using Quill JS Text Editor With Angular 7". I have done everything as shown but I am getting this error:

```html
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for NgControl ("
<form [FormGroup="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()"]>
<div class="form-group">
   [ERROR ->]
   <quill-editor formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
</div>
<ion-button type="submit">
Submit</ion"): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@11:2
Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for NgControl ("
<form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
<div class="form-group">
   [ERROR ->]
   <quill-editor formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
</div>
<ion-button type="submit">
Submit</ion"): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@11:2
at syntaxError (compiler.js:2420)
```

My `home.html` code:

```html
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
   <form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
   <div class="form-group">
      <quill-editor formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
   </div>
   <ion-button type="submit">Submit</ion-button>
   </form>
   The world is your oyster.
   <p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
</ion-content>
```

`home.ts` code:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
editorForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(){
// console.log(quill.container.innerHTML);
this.editorForm = new FormGroup({
'editor': new FormControl(null)
})
}
OnSubmit(){
console.log(this.editorForm.get('editor').value);
}
}
```

I have imported FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  in `app.module.ts` and `home.module.ts` but nothing is working.

How can I resolve this error and get the value of Quill editor?

### Edit 1

After small code correction[brackets], now it is saying:

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Comment: i have corrected it, now its saying `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.`

Comment: Hi user2828442. Jut a quick reminder that quote blocks (using the > device) are only for quotes, and are not a general highlighter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add `ReactiveFormsModule` to `imports` section of `HomeModule`.
It is the first step of [reactive forms guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).